# Help with Linq query, need to set ID based on results of a sub-query

Tags: c#, linq

My link query currently looks like:

```
var products =
(
    from p in products
    where !p.parentID.HasValue          
    select new ProductList
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        WarehouseID = p.WarehouseID,
        IsInStock = products.Any(p1 => p1 ... )
    }       
).ToArray();
```

What I need to happen according to business rules is:

If `IsInStock` is set to `true`, I need to assign the value for `WarehouseID` from `p1.WarehouesID`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't as straightforward as you might like. Nonetheless, here's a way to do it (assuming that `WarehouseID` is an `int`):

```
var products =
(
    from p in products
    where !p.parentID.HasValue

    select new ProductList
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        WarehouseID = (int)(products.Where(p1 => p1 ... ).Select(p1 => (int?)p1.WharehouseID).FirstOrDefault() ?? p.WarehouseID),
        IsInStock = products.Any(p1 => p1 ... )
    }


)
.ToArray();
```

By way of explanation, the casts to `int?` and `int` are required, since `FirstOrDefault` on a result expecting an `int` would return `0`, not a `null` `int?`. I've cast it to an `int?` here to allow us to determine if the result is, in fact, `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a let statment:

```
var products =
  (
   from p in products
   where !p.parentID.HasValue
   let p1Id = products.Where(p1 => p1 ... ).Select(p1 => p1.WarehouseID).FirstOrDefault()
   select new ProductList
   {
    Name = p.Name,
    WarehouseID = p1Id == 0 ? p.WarehouseID : p1Id,
    IsInStock = p1Id != 0
   }


  )
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `.ToArray()` at the end.

Then just add the condition:

```
if (IsInStock()) 
 products = products.where(p => p.WarehouseID > 10);
else
 products = products.where(p => p.WarehouseId < 10);
```

After everything, just add return `.ToArray()` and the query will be executed with the ifs.

Got the point?